# How do I know which object was selected in a select box or is it possible to bind an object to the KnockoutJS view model?

Tags: javascript, mvvm, knockout.js

I have an array of objects that I have binded to a `select` HTML element. When the user changes options on the `select` element, I can bind the value to the KnockoutJS view model. However, I need to map this value back to the original JavaScript object (as I need to access other properties to do perform other logic).

My HTML looks like this.

```
<select data-bind="options: categories, 
    optionsText: 'name',
    optionsValue: 'id',
    value: selectedCategory,
    optionsCaption: 'Choose...',
    event: { change: categoryChanged }
    ">
</select>
```

My JavaScript looks like the following.

```
var categories = [
    { "name" : "color", "id": "1" },
    { "name" : "names", "id": "2" }
];
var Category = function(data) {
    this.name = ko.observable(data.name);
    this.id =  ko.observable(data.id);
};
var Value = function(data) {
    this.name = ko.observable(data.name);
}
var ViewModel = function(categories, values) {
    var self = this;
    self.categories = ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(categories, function(category) {
        return new Category(category);
    }));
    self.selectedCategory = ko.observable();
    self.categoryChanged = function(obj, event) {
        //how do i map back to which category was selected?
        //do i have to loop through?
    };
};
var viewModel;
$(document).ready(function() { 
    viewModel = new ViewModel(categories);
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
});
```

JSFiddle code is at http://jsfiddle.net/jwayne2978/sx4e2f0r/.

When the user changes selection, I can access which category id was selected through `self.selectedCategory`, but I now need to map this category id back to an actual `Category`. I suppose I can iterate over `self.categories`, but that seems kind of against the purpose of KO.

Is there any way to bind a whole object to the view model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried removing `optionsValue: 'id'`? You would then be binding to the observable itself, and not just the `id` property.